# Using Zend Lucene in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, full-text-search, zend-search-lucene

I am creating a webapp in Cakephp, and am thinking of implementing a search function in it. I read about Zend Lucene providing the search capabilities for native PHP webapps.

I have my web pages all created without using any kind of database functionality. How will I able to add webpages to the indexes? I don't mean the code, just an idea would help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Lucene, but a start, if you're using cake, would be to put the existing pages under the control of the Cake pages controller - read about it in the book http://book.cakephp.org or google more information.

After that, I would probably start thinking about using `fgetss()` or something like that to scrape the pages.

Me? I'd get the existing pages into the database and set up a Article[n]-[m]Word datamodel. Much easier to deal with them then.